# cannot load such file -- plist Catalina and Xcode 12.4

Tags: ruby, xcode, rubygems, cocoapods, macos-catalina

Trying to build a project I get this error

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require': cannot load such file -- plist (LoadError)
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
from ../bin/merge_config.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

I tried installing manually the gem

```
gem install plist activesupport xcodeproj
```

But I still get the error

which ruby gets me

```
/usr/local/opt/ruby@2.6/bin/ruby
```

But to be honest I don't know if this is Ruby or Brew or Cocoapods or macOS or Xcode related
Others co/workers environments looks the same and works fine

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution was actually pretty obvious, just had to add this to the `/etc/paths`

```
/usr/local/opt/ruby@2.6/bin
```